# ADSK: POST Complete Upload to OSS returns "InvalidUploadKey"

Tags: autodesk-data-management

Good day, I am working through the Step-by-step tutorials for the Autodesk Design Automation API and I am getting an error on Task 6 - Prepare Cloud Storage.
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step6-prepare-cloud-storage/

I am able to Create an OSS Bucket and get a signed URL. When I upload a file (10MB) to the provided URL, I get a status code of 200.

When I try to complete the upload via the endpoint at the link below, I get an error, status code = 400.
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-signeds3upload-POST/

Here is the response body:

```
{"uploadKey":"[UPLOADKEY_REMOVED]","status":"error","reason":"InvalidUploadKey"}
```

The uploadKey is unchanged after it is received alongside the signed URL. The following headers are included in the POST request:

```
{
"Authorization": "Bearer <token>",
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"x-ads-meta-Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
}
```

The uploadKey is sent as:

```
{
"uploadKey":"[UPLOADKEY_REMOVED]"
}
```

I have tried with the x-ads-meta-content-type removed from the headers, and I get the same response. Again, no change is made to the uploadKey between receiving it in step 2 in the tutorial and submitting this post request. Maybe there is something wrong with how the file is uploaded in the put request, but I get a status 200 after uploading, so not sure. I have read that escape characters can be inserted if copied, but I'm using the strings directly from step 2, no copy/modification.

Any assistance is much appreciated!  Thanks

Comment: Did you cross check if the uploadKey is same as what you get in [Step 2](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step6-prepare-cloud-storage/#step-2-obtain-signed-url-to-upload-the-input-file) ?

Comment: Yes, I print the uploadKey when received and right before the POST request and they are exactly the same.

Comment: I don't see any reason why it is failing if you have followed exact steps, can you try in postman ? Pick any postman collection of your choice based on Engine.

https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-tutorial-postman/tree/master/DA4ACAD

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I built the requests manually to make sure I understood it and have it working in Postman, but still can't get it working with any other code. I have tried cUrl, Javascript and Python, some adapted directly from Postman. Still get the same message. I have included "Host":"developer.api.autodesk.com" in the headers since Postman included it and wouldn't work without it, but that hasn't changed the response. The data payload is sent as a string of a JSON. Any chance there's a block on certain User-Agent values?

Comment: Testing between Postman and the server I found that I was re-generating the objectKey between getting the signed URL and completing the upload. Issue is resolved.